# Read LTO Tape ID Tag

Tags: tape, tapedrive, lto

LTO 6 Tapes contain a ID tag within the casing (I assume its RFID). Is it possible to read the tag via `mt` commands?

I would like to identify the tape that is currently loaded in the tape drive.
I'm not using a tape loader. Thus the barcode scanner is not relevant here.

Comment: I am only aware that the id is taken from the barcode and might be changed to the tape in case, the writing starts afaik